# How to get the Virtual Good sales report on the Blackberry App World developer portal?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-world

I have a virtual good on sales inside a Blackberry 10 free application. However, I wonder how to check the sales report of this virtual good.

Comment: not a programming question, seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I had to check "Include Virtual Goods" on the Generate Charts page.